How can I stop Rsync from preserving timestamps?
I am using Rsync to install/outstall files from a git repository. Github ignores file timestamps. I want Rsync to do the same. I am using the following bash function to execute Rsync:
Rsync() {
   # git does not store permissions or times
   rsync \
      --executability \
      --filter="merge $HOME/.rsync-filter" \
      --filter="dir-merge /.rsync-filter" \
      --filter='- README.md' \
      --hard-links \
      --human-readable \
      --ignore-times \
      --itemize-changes \
      --keep-dirlinks \
      --links \
      --mkpath \
      --omit-dir-times \
      --one-file-system \
      --open-noatime \
      --partial \
      --preallocate \
      --recursive \
      --safe-links \
      --sparse \
      --no-acls \
      --no-atimes \
      --no-crtimes \
      --no-perms \
      --no-times \
      --no-xattrs \
      "$@"
}

Rsync --dry-run SOUCE DEST says:
>f..T...... .nanorc

About the plain file .nanorc (no link) claiming a timestamp difference exists while not proclaiming any difference in content. diff reports no difference between the files . ls -l  reports a difference in modification times.
Output from ls:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 468 24.03.13-07.23 home/.nanorc
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 468 24.10.29-08.49 /home/me/.nanorc

How can I cause Rsync to ignore the difference it reports as a T in the fifth position?

How about adding --no-times to that stack of config options? As explained here:

--no-times will avoid copying the timestamp, but if a file is updated, the target file will have its modification time set to now. That means the timestamps will now differ, so the next rsync will think an update is needed, and will send it again!

The example command for properly using --no-times is that:
rsync -i -a --no-times --checksum /source/Linux/ /destination/Linux

